# How to add all cell in a column that has a matching number in two different columns

Tags: excel, formula

I'm looking for a Excel formula that adds the "Net Dollars" column R for every order number that is in column T.

Here is where it gets tricky for me at least, basically I put a order number in column T in no particular order, and it highlights the order in column D per line item on that order.

But the net dollars for each line item is in column R, basically column T is irrelevant to which row the rest of the spread sheet is in but column's A through R are relevant.

I'll attach a pic and hopefully what i'm explaining makes sense.

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnKIi.png)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? It's a little unclear, but have you looked at `SUMIF()`?

Comment: havent tried anything, cant wrap my head around how to "word" the formula. I been reading on the sumif just haven't figured it out.

Comment: Where are you going to put the total amount, what column?

Comment: the first order in column D is "G36023-00" this order number is displayed for every line item on the order, see how some order numbers are displayed twice. the price for each line item is in column R, so when i load a truck i put the order # in column T that was loaded in no particular order. G36023 is in that column (T) but down further off the screen. so i want the total "Net Dollars" that is  "shipping today" from column R, this spread sheet is a few thousand rows long so there is many not shipping today. hopefully that clears this up. and thanks for taking time for me!

Comment: but i would like this total displayed in T3 under "todays deliveries"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this thread](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26461), try this in `T3`:

`=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D3:D6,T4:T5,0))=FALSE,R3:R6,0))`

Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

Adjust the ranges so that it matches your actual ranges. In my example:

`D3:D6` is the range of "Order Numbers"
`T4:T5` is the range of "Today's Deliveries"
`R3:R6` is the range of "Net Dollars"

Comment: okay, this seems to just sum everthing that is in the R range, for example if i make a =SUM(R3:R100) it returns the same result as =SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D3:D1000,T4:T1000,0))=FALSE,R3:R100,0))

Comment: okay that did work, i forgot to hit ctrl+shift+enter, 5 mins ago i didnt know what an array formula was, ty so much!

Answer (score 0):

The SUMIFS() function would do this much more simply.

=SUMIFS( Dollars, Number, D4, Deliveries, D4)

Textbook syntax
SUMIFS( sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2, ... criteria_range_n, criteria_n] )

SUMIFS, COUNTIFS, AVERAGEIFS, etc make performing computations based on multiple criteria very simple. One challenge is that all ranges must be the same dimensions.